# How to set event handlers via new RTTI? [D2010]

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, rtti

Playing with new RTTI module, I couldn't find a way to set an event handler with the new utilities. Trying something like this:

```
LProp := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(Form1.ClassInfo).AsInstance.GetProperty('OnClick');
LProp.SetValue(Form1, {a TValue!});
```

SetValue needs a TValue passed but I've yet to find a way to represent a TMethod via a TValue. Any comments?

ps. And a side question.. It seems prefixing RTTI variables with "L" is a convention (and a good one IMO, meta code turns into a puzzle real quick). But what does it actually stand for?

Comment: "L" is for local variables. You'll see that convention throughout the Indy source code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140562/does-my-variable-naming-convention-have-a-name/1140845#1140845

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make TValue contain a value of an aribtrary type with the From method.  Try something like this:

```
lValue := TValue.From<TNotifyEvent>(eventHandler);
```

BTW I think the L just means a **L**ocal variable.