# Howto set event handlers with arbitrary type with RTTI in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, rtti

after reading the post [How to set event handlers via new RTTI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482461/how-to-set-event-handlers-via-new-rtti-d2010), I wonder if it is possible to solve this more dynamically. For example I want to set ALL event handlers of any component to nil.

Using `TValue.From <TNotifyEvent> (SomeMethod)` does not work for two reasons:
1. The type is unknown (could be TNotifyEvent, TMouseEvent etc.)
2. I cannot set 'SomeMethod' to nil (invalid cast)

In old RTTI style I would do something like:

```
var
  NilMethod: TMethod;
begin
[...]
NilMethod.Data := nil;
NilMethod.Code := nil;
SetMethodProp (AComponent,PropertyName,NilMethod);
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the old style? Doesn't it still work?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the old style. I just wanted to use the same style for setting a handler to nil as well as for changing it.
The old style requires the Method Code to be published if I want to change it. Using the new style it can also be public or private, which I like better in this case. So do I really have to mix up both solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code ought to work:

```
procedure NilAllEventHandlers(myObject: TObject);
var
   context: TRttiContext;
   rType: TRttiType;
   field: TRttiField;
   value: TValue;
   nilMethod: TMethod;
begin
   nilMethod.Code := nil;
   nilMethod.Data := nil;

   context := TRttiContext.Create;
   rType := context.GetType(TButton);
   for field in rType.GetFields do
   begin
      if field.FieldType.TypeKind = tkMethod then
      begin
         TValue.Make(@nilMethod, field.FieldType.Handle, value);
         field.SetValue(myObject, value);
      end;
   end;
end;
```

But it doesn't because there's a bug in TValue.TryCast when working with a TMethod value whose .Code parameter is **nil**.  I'll report it to QC.  Hopefully it'll get fixed in D2011 or an update.  Until then, try the old style.

EDIT: Reported as [QC# 81416](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=81416).  Vote it up if you want to see it fixed.