# How to assign event handler to event property using RTTI?

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a class that has a few event properties, and another class that contains the event handlers. At compile-time I don't know the structure of either class, at run-time I only get to know the match between event property and event handler using their names. Using RTTI, I'd like to assign the event handlers to the respective event properties, how can I do so?

I currently have something like this:

```
type
  TMyEvent = reference to procedure(const AInput: TArray<string>; out AOutput: TArray<string>);
  TMyBeforeEvent = reference to procedure(const AInput: TArray<string>; out AOutput: TArray<string>; out ACanContinue: boolean);

  TMyClass = class
  private
    FOnBeforeEvent: TMyBeforeEvent;
    FOnEvent: TMyEvent;
  public
    property OnBeforeEvent: TMyBeforeEvent read FOnBeforeEvent write FOnBeforeEvent;
    property OnEvent: TMyEvent read FOnEvent write FOnEvent;
  end;

  TMyEventHandler = class
  public
    procedure DoBeforeEvent(const AInput: TArray<string>; out AOutput: TArray<string>; out ACanContinue: boolean);
    procedure DoEvent(const AInput: TArray<string>; out AOutput: TArray<string>);
  end;

  procedure AssignEvent;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Dialogs, System.RTTI;

{ TMyEventHandler }

procedure TMyEventHandler.DoBeforeEvent(const AInput: TArray<string>;
  out AOutput: TArray<string>; out ACanContinue: boolean);
begin
  // do something...
end;

procedure TMyEventHandler.DoEvent(const AInput: TArray<string>;
  out AOutput: TArray<string>);
begin
  // do something...
end;

procedure AssignEvent;
var
  LObj: TMyClass;
  LEventHandlerObj: TMyEventHandler;
  LContextObj, LContextHandler: TRttiContext;
  LTypeObj, LTypeHandler: TRttiType;
  LEventProp: TRttiProperty;
  LMethod: TRttiMethod;
  LNewEvent: TValue;
begin
  LObj := TMyClass.Create;
  LEventHandlerObj := TMyEventHandler.Create;

  LContextObj := TRttiContext.Create;
  LTypeObj := LContextObj.GetType(LObj.ClassType);
  LEventProp := LTypeObj.GetProperty('OnBeforeEvent');

  LContextHandler := TRttiContext.Create;
  LTypeHandler := LContextHandler.GetType(LEventHandlerObj.ClassType);
  LMethod := LTypeHandler.GetMethod('DoBeforeEvent');

  LEventProp.SetValue(LObj, LNewEvent {--> what value should LNewEvent have?});
end;
```

Comment: Have you ween this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482461/how-to-set-event-handlers-via-new-rtti-d2010

Comment: @fpiette yes I have, but I didn't know how to obtain a `TMethod` from the `TRttiMethod` I already had...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question!

I *believe* I have found a sound approach.

To illustrate it, create a new VCL application with a form (`Form1`) and a single button (`Button1`) on it. Give the form an `OnClick` handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(Self.Caption);
end;
```

We will attempt to assign this handler to the button's `OnClick` property using only RTTI and property and method names (as strings).

The key thing to remember is that a method pointer is a pair (code pointer, object pointer), specifically, a `TMethod` record:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  C: TRttiContext;
  b, f: TRttiType;
  m: TRttiMethod;
  bp: TRttiProperty;
  handler: TMethod;
begin

  C := TRttiContext.Create;

  f := C.GetType(TForm1);
  m := f.GetMethod('FormClick');

  b := C.GetType(TButton);
  bp := b.GetProperty('OnClick');

  handler.Code := m.CodeAddress;
  handler.Data := Form1;

  bp.SetValue(Button1, TValue.From<TNotifyEvent>(TNotifyEvent(handler)));

end;
```

Comment: Why TRttiContext.Create.Create ?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! The only thing I had to change in my code was the declaration of `TMyEvent` and `TMyBeforeEvent` from `reference to procedure` to `procedure of object` (in `TValue.From<TMyEvent>(TMyEvent(handler))` I had an _Invalid typecast_ error from the compiler)

Comment: I would suggest changing `handler` to `TNotifyEvent`, and then type-cast when setting its `Code` and `Data`, not when passing it to `TValue`, eg: `var handler: TNotifyEvent; ... TMethod(handler).Code := m.CodeAddress; TMethod(handler).Data := Self; bp.SetValue(Button1, TValue.From(handler));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's purely a matter of taste; personally I don't even think I have a preference. The benefit is that the type is more specific, but in practice you need one more cast (or you can use the highly popular `with` construct or the `absolute` keyword...).

Answer (score 6):

A `reference to procedure(...)` is an *anonymous method type*.  Under the hood, it is implemented as an interfaced object (ie, a class that implements the `IInterface` interface) with an `Invoke()` method that matches the parameters of the `procedure`.

So, can't use `TMyEventHandler.DoBeforeEvent()` *directly* with `TMyClass.OnBeforeEvent`, for instance, since `TMyEventHandler` does not match that criteria.  But, you can wrap the call to `DoBeforeEvent()` inside of an actual anonymous procedure, eg:

```pascal
procedure AssignEvent;
var
  LObj: TMyClass;
  LEventHandlerObj: TMyEventHandler;
  LEventHandler: TMyBeforeEvent;
  LContextObj: TRttiContext;
  LMethod: TRttiMethod;
  LEventProp: TRttiProperty;
begin
  LObj := TMyClass.Create;
  LEventHandlerObj := TMyEventHandler.Create;

  LContextObj := TRttiContext.Create;
  LMethod := LContextObj.GetType(LEventHandlerObj.ClassType).GetMethod('DoBeforeEvent');

  LEventHandler := procedure(const AInput: TArray<string>; out AOutput: TArray<string>; out ACanContinue: boolean);
  begin
    // Note: I don't know if/how TRttiMethod.Invoke() can handle
    // 'out' parameters, so this MAY require further tweaking...
    LMethod.Invoke(LEventHandlerObj, [AInput, AOutput, ACanContinue]);
  end;

  LEventProp := LContextObj.GetType(LObj.ClassType).GetProperty('OnBeforeEvent');
  LEventProp.SetValue(LObj, TValue.From(LEventHandler));
end;
```

Same with using `TMyEventHandler.DoEvent()` with `TMyClass.OnEvent`.

---

Alternatively, if you change the `reference to procedure(...)` into `procedure(...) of object` instead, you can then use the [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) record to assign `TMyEventHandler.DoBeforeEvent()` *directly* to `TMyClass.OnBeforeEvent`, eg:

```pascal
procedure AssignEvent;
var
  LObj: TMyClass;
  LEventHandlerObj: TMyEventHandler;
  LEventHandler: TMyBeforeEvent;
  LContextObj: TRttiContext;
  LEventProp: TRttiProperty;
  LMethod: TRttiMethod;
begin
  LObj := TMyClass.Create;
  LEventHandlerObj := TMyEventHandler.Create;

  LContextObj := TRttiContext.Create;

  LEventProp := LContextObj.GetType(LObj.ClassType).GetProperty('OnBeforeEvent');
  LMethod := LContextObj.GetType(LEventHandlerObj.ClassType).GetMethod('DoBeforeEvent');

  with TMethod(LEventHandler) do
  begin
    Code := LMethod.CodeAddress;
    Data := LEventHandlerObj;
  end;

  LEventProp.SetValue(LObj, TValue.From(LEventHandler));
end;
```

Same with using `TMyEventHandler.DoEvent()` with `TMyClass.OnEvent`.