# Is there a distinct name for prefix notation used in Delphi oftenly?

Tags: delphi, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does my variable naming convention have a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140562/does-my-variable-naming-convention-have-a-name)

Notation in question is described by example below:

- `T` for **t**ype
- `P` for **p**ointer
- `F` for **f**ield
- `A` for **a**rgument
- `L` for **l**ocal

et cetera, there is at least S missing from the list, but i'm not sure which string it designates.

First 3 prefices was with Delphi since very beginning, last 2 i've noticed relatively recently. I'd like to know notation name (if any), and read some normative whitepaper (and adopt then, may be).

Comment: You could add e.g. `E` for *e*xception, `On` for events. And a small prefix without vocals for enumerations (e.g. `bkCustom` for `TBitBtnKind`). See the [JVCL naming](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/StyleGuide.htm#3.0)

Comment: A has been around since Turbo Pascal days. (But somehow I never realized that it stands for "argument".) My personal prefix for arguments is _ (underscore) because it is less distracting.

Comment: This notation is ***not*** called Hungarian notation. Hungarian notation is the notation in which variable names use prefixes to indicate their types, such as `lpClassName` (long pointer), `dwStyle` (double word), and `hMenu` (handle). The Delphi prefix notation says nothing about the type of the identifier. For instance, `FPrevValue` can be a string, it can be an integer, it can even be a record. Instead, the Delphi prefix convention says something about the very basic nature of the identifier. *Types* are prefixed with `T` unless they are pointers (prefix `P`) or exceptions (prefix `E`).

Comment: *Filed* variables are prefixed with `F`, no matter what type they are. Function/procedure *arguments* are (sometimes) prefixed with `A` no matter what type they are.

Comment: @David M, thanks for the link. However i must say that their remark regarding Hungarian Notation gave me LOLWUTs (literally: "*Delphi is created in California, so we discourage the use of notation*")

Answer (score 5):

Zarko Gajic has a pretty good Delphi-specific list here:
http://delphi.about.com/od/standards/l/bldnc.htm

Personally, I find some conventions like this useful. I still remember my first language FORTRAN, where the convention for Integers was to start them any letter from I to N, and it was easy to remember because they are the first two letters of INteger.

[Section "3.3 Field Naming" of the Object Pascal Style Guide](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/StyleGuide.htm#3.3) by Charles Calvert gives a brief but good guide as to when to use Hungarian notation, and also what single character identifier names are appropriate. My FORTRAN background (8 character names max) also made me use "N" as the count of items and led to code such as:

```
   DO 10 I = 1, N
     DO 20 J = I, N
       ...
20   CONTINUE
10 CONTINUE
```

Ouch! The memories hurt.

Comment: Yeah, IIRC, there was IMPLICIT <type>(<prefix-list>)

Comment: The Zarko list add the type of the local variable in the name. This is not VCL standard, and since the variable is local, you will have no difficulty to retrieve its type. For components, it does make more sense to use a prefix, since the declaration can be out of scope. The JCVL's article **is** the reference.

Comment: @user759588: Yes. The FORTRAN default was: IMPLICIT REAL(A-H, O-Z), IMPLICIT INTEGER(I-N)

Comment: OMG! This isn't really Hungarian notation! But, since I am not that pedantic, I will vote you up. ;)

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite of all these standards, is to obey the standards already established in the code you're in, and not try to impose a different standard 50% of the way through, and to religiously avoid bikeshed discussions.

But if you press me really hard, I'll admit, I prefer Charlie Calvert's standards as used by [JVCL devs](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/StyleGuide.htm), same as "section 3.3" link by LKessler above.

Answer (score 0):

[Hungarian notation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)

With modern IDEs (including Delphi's) many people (myself included) feel it is no longer necessary.

EDIT: Technically this is not true Hungarian notation, as sometimes the prefix indicates the scope rather than the type.

Comment: It's handy in setter/getter methods to distinguish the arguments in/out from the class values being read or set.

Comment: I have found *ONE* case where I still use it--when the same data exists in a couple of formats.  This is rare but I've hit it in web stuff--everything comes in as a string no matter what it really is.  It seems more sensible to store the converted stuff in the same class than to copy everything to a new class while converting, especially as I still want the raw around for use in error messages.

Comment: -1 because: 1) Delphi is not true hungarian notation (you don't put the data type in the name) and 2) you state that it's no longer necessary. When the project grows, and when you are not the only one working on it, such unified notation is a must have. I suffered too much because code I had to review and modify was not using such notation. Sometimes, you just can't load the project in your IDE, and you'll have to load source file one by one. In this case, a standard naming convention helps a lot. Don't trust your feeling! :)

Comment: +1, I like Hungarian Notation in it's "Apps Hungarian" form.

Comment: Because of the unfortunate decision to make Pascal case insenstive, this prefix notation is more useful and desirable than in case sensitive languages

Comment: What Bouchez says. It is not Hungarian notation. And David, Delphi allows to use the same identifier as (field)type and identifier since D4, so not all cases are necessary anymore.  Though I do like its use in the designer. Identifiers are not just for code....

Comment: @Marco I'm mostly thinking of `FSomething` as the backing store for a property named `Something`.

Comment: -1 because this is simply wrong.

Comment: @Cosmin: Like it or not, the Delphi prefix convention has nothing to do with Hungarian notation.

Comment: @David: *Because of the unfortunate decision to make Pascal case insenstive* -> well, I have to disagree. What I find REALLY unfortunate is new case sensitive languages still being created in 21th century (C#, for example). There's no need for such dinossauric practice.....

Comment: @Andreas, re-reading the question, the OP is looking for the name of what appears to be the standard Delphi prefix notation. Unfortunately it's not the first time I misunderstand this user's question.

Comment: @Fabricio Look at the weight of numbers. New languages are case sensitive. Niklas Wirth changed tack with his work following Pascal. You just prefer insensitive because that's what you are used to. But a language that does not enforce letter case correctness just results in sloppy code.

Comment: @David: just purist BS. It just create more noise - it's an annoyance - and just that. TSQL is case insensitive also and my TSQL code is not different from my C# code in style and readability. Visual Basic is case insensitive and very readable. All C-descendant languages just have to envy the readability of Pascal - which is readable without that lame excuse ("just results in sloppy code").

Comment: @Fabricio My argument is very simple. I want the compiler to check things that I care about. I care about letter case. Every decent coder does. I'm sure you do. Case sensitivity has no impact whatsoever on readability. Do you have an argument in favour of insenstivity?

Comment: @David - it gives another way to create unmantainable code: creating any number of valid identifiers that differ only on case - but are different things. You cannot do this in Pascal, you cannot do this in Visual Basic, all variants that of SQL I heard of( Transact-SQL, PSQL (Firebird), PLSQL (Oracle), etc). Only on case sensitive languages.

Comment: @Fabricio But that's exactly what I want to be able to do. Experience tells me that your worries about unmaintainable code are unfounded.

Comment: (continuing) - So you trade something you cannnot harm yourself except on reading to something you can harm yourself because CASE have significance for the compiler. Case-sensivity just don't worth it.

Comment: You didn't saw code that do it, I do. And it's NIGHTMARISH. Case-sensivitiy is the stupidiest thing I've found in programming languages so far.

Comment: Case sensitivity allows you to have a variable named i and another named I, for example, in the same function....

Comment: This is specifically called out in the [Object Pascal Style Guide](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280) as *not* being Hungarian notation, with the exception of enumerated types.  This question is probably [a duplicate of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140562/does-my-variable-naming-convention-have-a-name) and my answer there goes into more detail.  No comment on the case-sensitivity thing :)

Comment: @David - agreed; I also voted to close after reading your link. But I still think this is Hungarian in spirit. :) Everyone else seems to be arguing "it has no name, but it's not Hungarian." Perhaps Eastwood Notation? Terence Hill Notation? ;)

Comment: @Warren - yup. If I find code using that kind of thing, I rename the identifier without a second thinking. Is crap code, and being case-insensitive Pascal doesn't allow this to happen. **It's a blessing**.